# 1-D discrete cosine transform(DCT)

Tags: dct, homework

This was a past year paper question. Not sure how to answer it.

Question: The 1-D discrete cosine transform(DCT) of a sequence f(x), x =0,1,...,N-1 is

F(u) = c(u)* Summation of f(x) cos ( (2x+1)u*pi/2N)

show that 1-D DCT of the sequence

g(x) = f(N-1-x), x = 0,1,...,N-1

can be expressed as G(u) = (-1)*F(u), u=0,1..., N-1

My solution (If wrong please correct me)

G(u) = c(u)* Summation of f(N-1-x) cos ((2(N-1-x)+1)u*pi/2N) 
     = c(u)* Summation of f(N-1-x) cos (2N-2x-1)u*pi/2N)

Comment: This one should be pretty simple. Try substituting $F(N-1-x)$ into the given formula for the DCT and manipulate the expression algebraically to see if you can pull out a $(-1)$ factor. It's easier than you think.

Comment: i will paste my solution below my question. If wrong please correct me....

Comment: not really sure brother need your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g(x)= f(N-1-x)$ then
$$\begin{aligned}
  (\operatorname{DCT}\:g)(u)
    =& c(u)\cdot\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}g(x)\cdot\cos\bigl((2x+1)u\cdot\tfrac\pi{2N}\bigr)
  \\=& c(u)\cdot\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}f(N-1-x)
        \cdot\cos\bigl((2N-2N+1+2x)u\cdot\tfrac\pi{2N}\bigr)
  \\=& c(u)\cdot\sum_{(N-1-x)=(N-1)}^{0}f(N-1-x)
        \cdot\cos\Bigl(\bigl(2N-1-2(N-1-x)\bigr)u\cdot\tfrac\pi{2N}\Bigr)
\end{aligned}$$
substitute now $N-1-x=:\xi$,
$$\begin{aligned}
  (\operatorname{DCT}\:g)(u)
    =& c(u)\cdot\sum_{\xi=0}^{N-1}f(\xi)
        \cdot\cos\Bigl(\bigl(2N-1-2\xi\bigr)u\cdot\tfrac\pi{2N}\Bigr)
  \\=& c(u)\cdot\sum_{\xi=0}^{N-1}f(\xi)
        \cdot\cos\Bigl(\pi\bigl(\tfrac{2N}{2N}-\tfrac{2\xi+1}{2N}\bigr)u\Bigr).
\end{aligned}$$
In the cosine, we have now a shift by an integer multiple ($u$) of $\pi$. Such a shift in a sine or cosine function is equivalent to multiplying the function with $(-1)^u$, So the result is
$$\begin{aligned}
  (\operatorname{DCT}\:g)(u)
    =& c(u)\cdot\sum_{\xi=0}^{N-1}f(\xi)
        \cdot\cos\bigl(\pi\tfrac{2\xi+1}{2N}u\bigr)\cdot(-1)^u
  \\=& (-1)^u\cdot(\operatorname{DCT}\:f)(u).
\end{aligned}$$
Not quite the expression you wanted to show, but this should be the correct one.